# Set policy in Windows 7 to deny removable devices

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

How I can set a policy in Windows 7 to deny the removable devices?

Comment: What version of Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

well, it can be set under the local group policy, you need to have elevated privileges.

click windows Button (bottom-left)
type "**gpedit.msc**" and hit return to launch the group policy editor

on the Hierarchy panel (the left one) go to:
Computer Configuration –> Administrative Templates –> System –> Device Installation –> Device Installation Restrictions

on the setting panel (the right one)
double click on "**Prevent installation of removable device**"
select enabled -> click on OK

to test the new setting open a command prompt with elevated privileges and type:
"**gpupdate /force**"

Note: if now you are interested in others settings of "Device Installation Restrictions", and want to enable one of them, don't forget to disable this one.

Comment: tnx alot man, it was good .